# How do I find the ID of a web part?

Tags: web-part

I have a web part that saves preferences to an external database because they are used by an outside program.  One of the key fields for the preferences is the ID of the web part so each web part instance can have separate preferences.  I didn't expose the ID of the web part in the editor so now I can see the ID in the database but I don't know to which web part instance it belongs.

Is there a way to find the ID of a web part without having to modify the code to expose it and redeploy the solution?

Answer (score 1):

See if you can use my answer from another similar question here on SPO
[How to get current web part GUID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/how-to-get-current-web-part-guid)

Comment: The link is no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

I believe JQuey can help you to find the instance ID of every web part on the page. But how are you going to send the same to your external database without writing code?

Here is more on the JQuer library: http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Comment: The existing code already knows the ID of the web part. I was hoping there was a way to find it administratively.