# Get Web Part Instance id from csom .net

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a web part app for sharepoint online. I wanted to know if it is possible to get the instance id of the web part, using csom on server side. For example, if I put the web part within a page, twice, I would like to know the two GUID generated for those two. I checked this ticket [How to get current web part GUID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/how-to-get-current-web-part-guid), but I am not sure how I can access the method `RenderContents`. The app is a provider-hosted app (azure), it was build using Visual Studio 2015 and it is an MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two listview webpart on same page then in SharePoint there is on class which is common in all listview "ms-listviewtable".

Use below code and iterate using each loop in jQuery.

$('.ms-listviewtable')

You will get HTML inside it and find unique GUID for both web part.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention I need to get the value from server side using csom. Is it possible?.